# Regular expression matching on comma bounded by nonwhite space

Tags: r, regex, regular-language

I am trying to replace commas bounded by nonwhite space with a white space, while keeping other commas untouched (in R).

Imagine I have:

```
j<-"Abc,Abc, and c"
```

and I want:

```
"Abc Abc, and c"
```

This almost works:

```
gsub("[^ ],[^ ]"," " ,j)
```

But it removes the characters either side of the commas to give:

```
"Ab bc, and c"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a PCRE regex with a negative lookbehind and lookahead:

```
j <- "Abc,Abc, and c"
gsub("(?<!\\s),(?!\\s)", " ", j, perl = TRUE)
## => [1] "Abc Abc, and c"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lRZzTq/1)

**Details**:

- `(?<!\\s)` -  there cannot be a whitespace right before a `,`
- `,` -  a literal `,`
- `(?!\\s)` -  there cannot be a whitespace right after a `,`

An alternative solution is to match a `,` that is enclosed with word boundaries:

```
j <- "Abc,Abc, and c"
gsub("\\b,\\b", " ", j)
## => [1] "Abc Abc, and c"
```

See [another R demo](https://ideone.com/pTbl6C).

Comment: Is this functionally equivalent: `"(?<=\\S),(?=\\S)"`?

Comment: No, negative lookarounds are not equivalent to positive ones as positive lookarounds require the presence of the pattern. Usually, the difference is seen at start/end of string positions. `(?<=\S)` requires a non-whitespace before the next subpattern, thus, there will be no match at the start of the string. `(?<!\s)` means there cannot be a whitespace before, but the start of string can be there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use back references like this:

```
gsub("([^ ]),([^ ])","\\1 \\2" ,j)
[1] "Abc Abc, and c"
```

The `()` in the regular expression capture the characters adjacent to the comma. The `\\1` and `\\2` return these captured values in the order they were captured.

Answer (score 3):

We can try

```
gsub(",(?=[^ ])", " ", j, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Abc Abc, and c"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it also works:

```
library("stringr")
j<-"Abc,Abc, and c"
str_replace(j,"(\\w+),([\\w]+)","\\1 \\2")
```